# How can I authorize API access with just a Phone number and SMS Pin?

Tags: api, rest, meteor, oauth

I'm creating a backend that has a REST API that will be consumed from an mobile app. Because the app is mobile only we're not using an email and password to create account/login but instead a phone number and then they receive a pin number with an SMS message to confirm they own the number.

After I confirm the user is who they say they are with the pin number, how should I go about authenticating future API requests?

My first thought was to create a token and return it to the app. My second thought was to use OAuth but then i'm getting confused as to which method would work with the Phone number/SMS login method (2/3 leg, grants, etc..). I don't fully understand how this might work when using OAuth with our own apps (as opposed to OAuth with another provider). The token seems like the easier route.

If I use the token, is it bad to use the same token until the user is logged out? (over https). I'm assuming it's worth the extra work to make them expire a little longer than the avg. user session.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a turn key solution that works with phone numbers. I'm using Meteor but am expecting to roll my own with Node modules (by exposing connect on the Meteor server).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify, are you using meteor on the mobile device? I don't have a solution but I would be interested in finding this out myself. Further more if you are using Cordova via meteor, how are you doing user management? This would be something I would like to see added to this package: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core

Comment: Sure, we're using legacy native apps, so no Objective-DDP or Cordova. So for this case it's going to be pretty much a 'node' app from the app's point of view. User management is done with https://atmospherejs.com/dispatch/accounts-sms  to login/create an account with SMS.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Sorry but I can not be of any help as I have not need to do that yet. If you do figure it out please answer your question. Eventually the community will want to standardize true native APIs.

Comment: Will do. So far the plan is to use an encrypted and signed Json Web Tokens (JWT) then add custom middleware with Iron Router to authorize every request. There's also Restivus but it's to rigid for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Twitter's Digits? It comes with their Fabric package which was pretty great during our last app development. It allows you to register and verify users through their phone number via twitter services. The package is pretty simple to install and beside the server-side token validation, you avoid a lot of hassle.

[Digits' documentation](http://docs.fabric.io/ios/digits/index.html)

And for the server side validation of the login:

[Digits: how can I verify DGTSession tokens on my own server?](https://twittercommunity.com/t/digits-how-can-i-verify-dgtsession-tokens-on-my-own-server/26036)